# Overide automatic padding with text?

Tags: html, css

whenever I'm using the p tag (or h1 etc. for that matter) there is always some spacing between each element. I've tried to overcome this by using `padding:0;` in a stylesheet but the spacing still remains. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
margin:0;
```

But the best option is to use a reset.css to default all elements out.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Most reset stylesheets won't zero the padding/margin of `<p>`; they will set it to some suitable consistent value.

Comment: If you look at the reset.css I linked to, it resets the margin to zero on all common elements, including <p> tags.

Comment: Using a reset to remove padding from `<p>` elements is counterproductive.

Comment: Despite your comments AND THE NEGATIVE VOTES (THANKS), a reset stylesheet is something I use when every project. It overcomes the inconsistencies between browsers and platforms. I'd rather set the padding manually on elements to ensure they render as expected.

Comment: @shamazing, agreed. Reset-stylesheets reduce the inconsistencies of browser-defaults to a near-zero level. They're not a cure-all, but they do help some of us. It's possible that the down-votes are because of the assertion that "...the best option is to use a reset...", rather than simply suggesting it might be useful. Anyhoo, +1 for recommending an approach I use myself.

Comment: Thanks, David. I am of the opinion that a reset is best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Try to also set the `margin` to 0.